# WebStorm - TypeScript and allowSyntheticDefaultImports flag

Tags: typescript, intellisense, webstorm, babeljs, definitelytyped

TypeScript 1.8 added [allowSyntheticDefaultImports flag](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-default-import-interop-with-systemjs).

I have a TypeScript project targeting es6, which afterwards gets transpiled with Babel to ES5.

Currently, WebStorm's intellisense does not recognize this flag, and thus says that using default import from a module which does not export a default is disallowed. This means that I am not getting the definitions correctly..

Since I do not want to update all of the definition files manually, is there any other way to 'teach' WebStorm this rule, until JetBrains officially release a new version which supports it (I already submitted a ticket there).

Comment: no, there is no way to 'teach' the parser to treat arbitrary stuff as a default module and provide the completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm doesn't appear to use the TypeScript language service, so there isn't any way that I'm aware of to fix this.

In the mean time you can use non-ES6 style imports:

```
import foo = require("foo");
```

which should basically compile down to:

```
var foo = require("foo");
```